# Creating an Inputbox in C# using forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Hello I'm currently creating an application which has the need to add server IP addresses to it, as there is no InputBox function in C# I'm trying to complete this using forms, but am very new to the language so not 100% as to what I should do.

At the moment I have my main form and a form which will act as my inputbox which wants to hide on load. Then when the user clicks on the add IP Address on the main form I wish to open up the secondary form and return the IP address entered into a text box on the secondary form.

So how would I go about doing this? Or is there any better ways to achieve similar results?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your main form, add an event handler for the event **Click** of button Add Ip Address. In the event handler, do something similar as the code below:

```
private string m_ipAddress;
private void OnAddIPAddressClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SetIPAddressForm form = new SetIPAddressForm())
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Create a property in SetIPAddressForm to return the input of user.
            m_ipAddress = form.IPAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Add another example to fit with *manemawanna* comment.

```
private void btnAddServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ipAdd;
    using(Input form = new Input())
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //Create a property in SetIPAddressForm to return the input of user.
            ipAdd = form.IPAddress;
        }
    }
}
```

In your Input form, add a property:

```
public class Input : Form
{
    public string IPAddress
    {
        get { return txtInput.Text; }
    }

    private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do some validation for the text in txtInput to be sure the ip is well-formated.

        if(ip_well_formated)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should better use the using() statement. :)

Comment: Well, we learn stuff every day :), I applied using keyword in my code on everything (Pen, SqlConnection, Stream, etc.) but I never did it on a form. Probably because I never saw an example applying it...even in a book.

Comment: This is what I currently have

     private void btnAddServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ipAdd;
        }

Not alot I know my other form which I wish to use is named Input it has a text box called txtInput and a button called btnInput. So how would this match what you've given as an answer? Sorry but I'm new to all this.

Comment: This has beena huge help to me, I was looking at 3rd party controls, but this was way better to implement myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the VB InputBox...

1. Add reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic
2. string result = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Title","text", "", 10, 20);

Answer (score 2):

I've needed this feature, too.  Here's my code; it auto-centers and sizes to fit the prompt.  The public method creates a dialog and returns the user's input, or `null` if they cancel.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utilities
{
public class InputBox
    {
    #region Interface
    public static string  ShowDialog(string prompt, string title, string defaultValue = null, int? xPos = null, int? yPos = null)
        {
        InputBoxDialog  form   = new InputBoxDialog(prompt, title, defaultValue, xPos, yPos);
        DialogResult    result = form.ShowDialog();
        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
            return null;
        else
            return form.Value;
        }
    #endregion

    #region Auxiliary class
    private class InputBoxDialog: Form
        {
        public string  Value  { get { return _txtInput.Text; } }

        private Label    _lblPrompt;
        private TextBox  _txtInput;
        private Button   _btnOk;
        private Button   _btnCancel;

        #region Constructor
        public InputBoxDialog(string prompt, string title, string defaultValue = null, int? xPos = null, int? yPos = null)
            {
            if (xPos == null && yPos == null)
                {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                }
            else
                {
                StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

                if (xPos == null)  xPos = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width  - Width ) >> 1;
                if (yPos == null)  yPos = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Height) >> 1;

                Location = new Point(xPos.Value, yPos.Value);
                }

            InitializeComponent();

            if (title == null)  title = Application.ProductName;
            Text = title;

            _lblPrompt.Text = prompt;
            Graphics  graphics = CreateGraphics();
            _lblPrompt.Size = graphics.MeasureString(prompt, _lblPrompt.Font).ToSize();
            int  promptWidth  = _lblPrompt.Size.Width;
            int  promptHeight = _lblPrompt.Size.Height;

            _txtInput.Location  = new Point(8, 30 + promptHeight);
            int  inputWidth = promptWidth < 206 ? 206 : promptWidth;
            _txtInput.Size      = new Size(inputWidth, 21);
            _txtInput.Text      = defaultValue;
            _txtInput.SelectAll();
            _txtInput.Focus();

            Height = 125 + promptHeight;
            Width  = inputWidth + 23;

            _btnOk.Location = new Point(8, 60 + promptHeight);
            _btnOk.Size     = new Size(100, 26);

            _btnCancel.Location = new Point(114, 60 + promptHeight);
            _btnCancel.Size     = new Size(100, 26);

            return;
            }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        protected void  InitializeComponent()
            {
            _lblPrompt           = new Label();
            _lblPrompt.Location  = new Point(12, 9);
            _lblPrompt.TabIndex  = 0;
            _lblPrompt.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

            _txtInput          = new TextBox();
            _txtInput.Size     = new Size(156, 20);
            _txtInput.TabIndex = 1;

            _btnOk              = new Button();
            _btnOk.TabIndex     = 2;
            _btnOk.Size         = new Size(75, 26);
            _btnOk.Text         = "&OK";
            _btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;

            _btnCancel              = new Button();
            _btnCancel.TabIndex     = 3;
            _btnCancel.Size         = new Size(75, 26);
            _btnCancel.Text         = "&Cancel";
            _btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            AcceptButton = _btnOk;
            CancelButton = _btnCancel;

            Controls.Add(_lblPrompt);
            Controls.Add(_txtInput);
            Controls.Add(_btnOk);
            Controls.Add(_btnCancel);

            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            MaximizeBox = false;
            MinimizeBox = false;

            return;
            }
        #endregion
        }
    #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a button in main form.

Create a form with textbox for ip address. (lets say it IPAddressForm)

Add click event handler for that button.

In the event handler, create an instance of IPAddressForm and call showdialog method of IPAddressForm.

Store the ip address in some class variable.

If the showdialog result is ok, read the class variable from main form (simplest way is to declare the field as public)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Francis has the correct idea which is what I would have suggested. However, just to add to this I would probably suggest using a MaskedTextBox instead of a basic TextBox and add the IP Address format as the Mask.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your special messagebox. I created my messagebox for getting database information like below. And when the messagebox open, application stop during you click any button in related messagebox.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace Palmaris_Installation
{
    public class efexBox
    {
        public static string ShowDialog()
        {
            PopUpDatabase form = new PopUpDatabase();
            DialogResult result = form.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                return null;
            else
            {
                if (form.ValueAuthentication == "SQL Server Authentication")
                return form.Valueservername + "?" + form.ValueAuthentication + "?" + form.ValueUsername + "?" + form.ValuePassword;
                else
                    return form.Valueservername + "?" + form.ValueAuthentication + "?" + "" + "?" + "";
            }
        }

        public partial class PopUpDatabase : Form
        {
            public PopUpDatabase()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                SqlDataSourceEnumerator instance = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance;
                DataTable table = instance.GetDataSources();

                foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                {
                    cmbServerName.Items.Add(row[0] + "\\" + row[1]);
                }
                cmbAuthentication.Items.Add("Windows Authentication");
                cmbAuthentication.Items.Add("SQL Server Authentication");
                return;
            }

            private void InitializeComponent()
            {
                this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
                this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
                this.cmbServerName = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
                this.cmbAuthentication = new System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox();
                this.txtUserName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.txtPassword = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
                this.btnCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.btnConnect = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
                this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
                this.MaximizeBox = false;
                this.groupBox1.SuspendLayout();
                this.SuspendLayout();

                // 
                // groupBox1
                // 
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnConnect);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.btnCancel);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtPassword);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.txtUserName);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cmbAuthentication);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.cmbServerName);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label4);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
                this.groupBox1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
                this.groupBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
                this.groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
                this.groupBox1.Name = "groupBox1";
                this.groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(348, 198);
                this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.groupBox1.TabStop = false;
                this.groupBox1.Text = "Database Configration";
                this.groupBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                // 
                // label1
                // 
                this.label1.AutoSize = true;
                this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 46);
                this.label1.Name = "label1";
                this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(69, 13);
                this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label1.Text = "Server Name";
                // 
                // label2
                // 
                this.label2.AutoSize = true;
                this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 73);
                this.label2.Name = "label2";
                this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 13);
                this.label2.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label2.Text = "Authentication";
                // 
                // label3
                // 
                this.label3.AutoSize = true;
                this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 101);
                this.label3.Name = "label3";
                this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 13);
                this.label3.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label3.Text = "User Name";
                // 
                // label4
                // 
                this.label4.AutoSize = true;
                this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50, 127);
                this.label4.Name = "label4";
                this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(53, 13);
                this.label4.TabIndex = 0;
                this.label4.Text = "Password";
                // 
                // cmbServerName
                // 
                this.cmbServerName.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                this.cmbServerName.FormattingEnabled = true;
                this.cmbServerName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 43);
                this.cmbServerName.Name = "cmbServerName";
                this.cmbServerName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 21);
                this.cmbServerName.TabIndex = 1;
                // 
                // cmbAuthentication
                // 
                this.cmbAuthentication.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
                this.cmbAuthentication.FormattingEnabled = true;
                this.cmbAuthentication.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 70);
                this.cmbAuthentication.Name = "cmbAuthentication";
                this.cmbAuthentication.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 21);
                this.cmbAuthentication.TabIndex = 1;
                this.cmbAuthentication.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.cmbAuthentication_SelectedIndexChanged);
                // 
                // txtUserName
                // 
                this.txtUserName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 98);
                this.txtUserName.Name = "txtUserName";
                this.txtUserName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 20);
                this.txtUserName.TabIndex = 2;
                // 
                // txtPassword
                // 
                this.txtPassword.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 124);
                this.txtPassword.Name = "txtPassword";
                this.txtPassword.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(185, 20);
                this.txtPassword.TabIndex = 2;
                // 
                // btnCancel
                // 
                this.btnCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(250, 163);
                this.btnCancel.Name = "btnCancel";
                this.btnCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                this.btnCancel.TabIndex = 3;
                this.btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
                this.btnCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                // 
                // btnConnect
                // 
                this.btnConnect.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(140, 163);
                this.btnConnect.Name = "btnConnect";
                this.btnConnect.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
                this.btnConnect.TabIndex = 3;
                this.btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                this.btnConnect.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                this.btnConnect.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                // 
                // PopUpDatabase
                // 
                this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
                this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
                this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(348, 198);
                this.Controls.Add(this.groupBox1);
                this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
                this.Name = "PopUpDatabase";
                this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
                this.Text = "::: Database Configration :::";
                this.groupBox1.ResumeLayout(false);
                this.groupBox1.PerformLayout();
                this.ResumeLayout(false);

            }

            private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtPassword;
            private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtUserName;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbAuthentication;
            private System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox cmbServerName;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnConnect;
            private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnCancel;

            public string ValueUsername { get { return txtUserName.Text; } }
            public string ValuePassword { get { return txtPassword.Text; } }
            public string Valueservername { get { return cmbServerName.SelectedItem.ToString(); } }
            public string ValueAuthentication { get { return cmbAuthentication.SelectedItem.ToString(); } }

            private void cmbAuthentication_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (cmbAuthentication.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    txtUserName.Enabled = true;
                    txtPassword.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtUserName.Enabled = false;
                    txtPassword.Enabled = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in your main application call like :

```
 string[] strPopUp = efexBox.ShowDialog().Split('?');
```